Create an object class matrix/array from data frame
I'd like to convert the data frame my df
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/refs/heads/main/Dados_C3_data_planta.csv", sep=";")
head(df)

#        Data GLY_PN CRO_P MIPU_P CEN_P POA01_P CECRO_P COM_P MOR_PN
#1 24-01-2024     53    40      3     0       0       0     0      0
#2 25-01-2024     56     8      0    24       9       0     0      0
#3 26-01-2024      0    27      0    47      26       0     0      0
#4 27-01-2024      0     0      0     0       0       6    43     48
#5 31-01-2024      0     0      0    62      35       0     0      0
#6 02-02-2024      0     0      0    50      50       0     0      0
#  COPA_PN RHY_P SOR_P
#1       0     0     0
#2       0     0     0
#3       0     0     0
#4       0     0     0
#5       0     0     0
#6       0     0     0

to class [1] "matrix" "array". I cannot bring it to work with as.matrix() or data.matrix().
Desirable output (~df_to_matrix()):
#                GLY_PN CRO_P MIPU_P CEN_P POA01_P CECRO_P COM_P MOR_PN
#1 24-01-2024     53    40      3     0       0       0     0      0
#2 25-01-2024     56     8      0    24       9       0     0      0
#3 26-01-2024      0    27      0    47      26       0     0      0
#4 27-01-2024      0     0      0     0       0       6    43     48
#5 31-01-2024      0     0      0    62      35       0     0      0
#6 02-02-2024      0     0      0    50      50       0     0      0
#  COPA_PN RHY_P SOR_P
#1       0     0     0
#2       0     0     0
#3       0     0     0
#4       0     0     0
#5       0     0     0
#6       0     0     0

class(df_to_matrix)
[1] "matrix" "array"

Column name in the first column and values in numeric format.

# Load the data
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/refs/heads/main/Dados_C3_data_planta.csv", sep=";")

# Convert to matrix, excluding the first column (dates)
df_to_matrix <- as.matrix(df[, -1])  # Exclude the first column

# Optionally, convert character columns to numeric
df_to_matrix <- apply(df_to_matrix, 2, as.numeric)

# Check the class
class(df_to_matrix)

# Print the resulting matrix
print(df_to_matrix)


Not sure if OP also wants the row names as in the example output. You can just add rownames(df_to_matrix) <- df[,1]

Convert the data frame to zoo and then to matrix.
library(zoo)
df |> read.zoo(format = "%d-%m-%Y") |> as.matrix()

giving this matrix with row names constructed from the first column normalized to use yyyy-mm-dd format which unlike the original format sorts in date order.
           GLY_PN CRO_P MIPU_P CEN_P POA01_P CECRO_P COM_P MOR_PN COPA_PN RHY_P SOR_P
2024-01-24     53    40      3     0       0       0     0      0       0     0     0
2024-01-25     56     8      0    24       9       0     0      0       0     0     0
2024-01-26      0    27      0    47      26       0     0      0       0     0     0
2024-01-27      0     0      0     0       0       6    43     48       0     0     0
2024-01-31      0     0      0    62      35       0     0      0       0     0     0
2024-02-02      0     0      0    50      50       0     0      0       0     0     0
2024-02-05      0     0      0     0       0       0     0      0      99     0     0
2024-02-06      0     0     81     0       0       0     0      0       0    17     0
2024-02-07      0     0      0    58      10       0     0      0       0     0    33
2024-02-09      0     0      0     0       0       0     0      0       0    32    64
2024-02-10      0     0      0    47      22       0     0      0       0     0    64


We can use as.matrix() with `row.names<-`().
`row.names<-`(as.matrix(d0[-1]), d0[[1]])

           GLY_PN CRO_P MIPU_P CEN_P POA01_P CECRO_P COM_P MOR_PN COPA_PN RHY_P SOR_P
24-01-2024     53    40      3     0       0       0     0      0       0     0     0
25-01-2024     56     8      0    24       9       0     0      0       0     0     0
26-01-2024      0    27      0    47      26       0     0      0       0     0     0
27-01-2024      0     0      0     0       0       6    43     48       0     0     0
31-01-2024      0     0      0    62      35       0     0      0       0     0     0
02-02-2024      0     0      0    50      50       0     0      0       0     0     0
05-02-2024      0     0      0     0       0       0     0      0      99     0     0
06-02-2024      0     0     81     0       0       0     0      0       0    17     0
07-02-2024      0     0      0    58      10       0     0      0       0     0    33
09-02-2024      0     0      0     0       0       0     0      0       0    32    64
10-02-2024      0     0      0    47      22       0     0      0       0     0    64

No external packages.
Data.
d0 = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/refs/heads/main/Dados_C3_data_planta.csv", sep=";")

